# Duplicate entities when setting state within a collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a solution which uses Entity Framework to insert invoices to a database table. These invoices reference an order, which in turn also references an order item collection.

In this instance I am trying to add an order to the database, however the code is inside a new DbContext and so I need to attach the order and order items to the context, as these already exist in the database and shouldn't be re-added.

I've cut down the model properties for the sake of demonstration:

```
public class Invoice {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<InvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineItem {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ShopifyOrderItem { get; set; }
}

public class ShopifyOrder {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    ...
    public OrderInvoiceStatus InvoiceStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ShopifyOrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class ShopifyOrderItem {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    [Required]
    public virtual ShopifyOrder ShopifyOrder { get; set; }
}
```

In the invoice engine, I'm running the following code for each invoice to add it to the database:

```
ShopifyOrder order = await db.ShopifyOrders.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderNumber.ToString() == inv.OrderNumber);

if (order != null) {
    // Attach marketplace entity to the invoice to avoid duplicate primary key exceptions
    db.Marketplaces.Attach(inv.Marketplace);
    db.Invoices.Add(inv);
    order.InvoiceStatus = OrderInvoiceStatus.InProgress;
}
```

I've tried a number of methods to try and attach the states, however they all throw errors.

```
inv.LineItems.ForEach(li => {
    db.Entry(li).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    db.Entry(li.ShopifyOrderItem).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    db.Entry(li.ShopifyOrderItem.ShopifyOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
});
```

The above code returns the following error on save:

> EntityFramework: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'TorroModels.ShopifyOrder' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model.

What is the best way to attach the LineItems/ShopifyOrderItems without trying to attach the ShopifyOrder connected property multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but it seems that you need to follow the best practice first when constructing a relationship. You may follow this link :

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

In short :

1. Avoid using only "Id" in every entity, or you can use attributes to map between the physical name and the property name
2. It seems that you have circular references here, so maybe you could simplify it first

Next, you can read this link :

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx

if you need to know more about what's the best practice of attaching entities, but in my opinion, just don't abuse this feature, because using normal CRUD should be sufficient most of the time.

I'm sorry I cannot help you more than this, because of lack of information I may need, and with my reputation I still cannot comment directly in your post to ask for it.